# Express JS : always get message : TypeError: Assignment to constant variable

Tags: express, authentication, jwt, token

I am  trying to create API with Express JS ,the API worked fine ,I made authorization for some routes with JsonWebToken package ,it is create token fine ,but when I used it I gave this error: **TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.**
the user controller sign in :

```
    login:(req,res)=>{
        const body=req.body;

        checkUserByEmail(body.email,(err,results)=>{
            if(err){
                return err;
            }
            else if(!results){
                return res.json({
                    success:0,
                    message : 'email not registered!'
                });
            }
            else{
                const result = bcrypt.compareSync(body.password,results.password);
                if(result){

                    const jsonToken = sign({
                        email:body.email,
                        name:results.name
                    },process.env.TOKEN_KEY,
                        {expiresIn : 60*60*24*30*12});
                    return res.json({
                        success:1,
                        message:'loggin successfully',
                        token :jsonToken
                    })  
                }
                else{
                    res.json({
                        success:0,
                        message:'password is wrong'
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    },
```

My auth method :

```
module.exports = {
    checkToken :(req,res,next)=>{
        const token = req.get('authorization');
        if(token){
            console.log(token);
            
            token=token.slice(7);
            verify(token,process.env.TOKEN_KEY,(err,decoded)=>{
                if(err){
                    return res.json({
                        success:0,
                        messgae:'invalid token'
                    });
                }else{
                    next();
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            return res.json({
                success:0,
                messgae:'access not allowed'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

### Can any one help?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the slice method of token :

```
token=token.slice(7);
```

the new auth method is :

```
module.exports = {
    checkToken :(req,res,next)=>{
        const authHeader = req.headers['authorization']
        const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1]
        if(token){ 
            verify(token,process.env.TOKEN_KEY,(err,decoded)=>{
                if(err){
                    return res.json({
                        success:0,
                        messgae:'invalid token'
                    });
                }else{
                    next();
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            return res.json({
                success:0,
                messgae:'access not allowed'
            });
        }
    }
}
```